# Quantity on the product card and subtotal disappear

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I use a Product Add-on, I have a problem with the functioning of the quantity on the product card, when there is no value in the input quantity, the subtotal disappears, how can I fix it so that the price is visible all the time at the product card, also the buttons for adding and subtracting quantity do not work

[image]

[image]